# Invalid API key of VisionAI

Tags: python, java

I have created a project that detects the prescription. I have used API key of VisionAI to process the request. After entering the API key in the code Im getting an error "Invalid Key". I have entered the credit card details correctly.

I want to know how to get the valid API key  to detect the contents in the image

Comment: The code would be very helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.